# GAE: About the "api" property in target "enhance_war"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datanucleus

The [GAE documentation for JPA 2.0](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2#Setting_Up_JPA_2_0) states that the target `enhance_war` for the ant file should be this:

```
  <target name="datanucleusenhance" depends="compile"
  description="Performs enhancement on compiled data classes.">
  <enhance_war war="war">
          <args>
          <arg value="-enhancerVersion"/>
          <arg value="v2"/>
      </args>
  </enhance_war>
```

However, we can find this on `ant-macros.xml`:

```
<attribute name="api" description="persistence api, JDO or JPA" default="JDO"/>
```

Is that correct, i.e., we are not supposed to specify the JPA usage?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, looking at [DataNucleus documentation](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/enhancer.html), in the Ant section, I read:

`api   Optional. Defines the API to be used when enhancing     JDO, JPA`

and JDO is the default, I would specify it as JPA when needed, even though it seems to work anyway.

Also it seems to me that the macro doesn't add a lot of value, so I've decided to integrate the enhance task directly in my configuration, so I can select only classes ending with Entity, instead of letting datanucleus check every class.

```
<target name="-datanucleusenhance" depends="compile"
        description="Performs enhancement on compiled data classes">
    <enhance failonerror="true" api="JPA">
        <arg value="-enhancerVersion"/>
        <arg value="v2"/>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${main.classes.dir}"/>
            <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/lib/appengine-tools-api.jar"/>                
        </classpath>
        <fileset dir="${war.dir}/WEB-INF/classes" includes="**/*Entity.class"/>
    </enhance>
</target>
```

Let me know what you've discovered in the meantime!

Comment: I didn't find out anything. Nobody in the Google Groups answered me and my feedback on the documentation wasn't responded.

Comment: In my tests, JPA works with api="JPA" and also with api="JDO", a more complex scenario might fail perhaps. I think Andy @DataNucleus knows what's going on, and if he has time, he could answer you or leave a comment.